# DataTables stuck on "Processing" when sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

Below is the document ready function

```
 $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "aaSorting": [[2, "asc"]],
            "sAjaxSource": "/userControl/GetUser.php",
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                "aTargets": [0],
                "mData": "download_link",
                "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<a href="/UserDetail.aspx?ID=' + data + '">Detail</a><br/><a href="/UserDetail.aspx?ID=' + data + '">Delete</a>';
                }
            }],
              "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": null },
            { "mData": "LoginId" },
            { "mData": "FirstName" },
            { "mData": "LastName" }
        ]
        });

    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    oTable.fnSort([1, 'asc']);
```

With the above code, the datatable was stuck on "Processing..." like the below screen shows, but if I remove the sorting, the data was shown correctly, but whenever the user request a column to be sort, the result was still the same, is there anything that I did wrong?
[image]

Comment: oTable.fnSort([[1, 'asc']]); should be oTable.fnSort([1, 'asc']);

Comment: I've changed it to oTable.fnSort([1, 'asc']);, but the result is still the same..

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman There are 4 records in the table

Comment: Seems like a lot of trouble to sort 4 records, pulling the sorted data down every time... Would it make more sense to sort locally (on the web page)?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman it's OK to sort on web page, and up till now there're 4 users, but later, more record will be added, but the problem is, the Datatable wasn't able to sort on web page

Comment: Switch to a different table control that can sort locally. How many records are we talking about when "later" arrives?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman about 200 records

Comment: @AdamZuckerman I can switch to a different table control, but do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I do not. There are several jQuery based tables with sorting capabilities. It should be an easy enough thing to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+table+with+sort&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed   "bServerSide": true, and the DataTables can sort and filter properly now

Comment: But only the fraction of data that comes from your ajax call. If you have several hundreds of users and you want to have pagination, you will need bServerSide. Sorting and filtering has then to be done on the serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side implementation has to handle sorting via the iSortCol parameters, using fnSort is for client-side implementations and will not work for server-side

As @mainguy said in his comment, removing bServerSide will disable pagination and more than likely search

Look at the examples for asp.net on the site, as thats the lang you tagged, if you need more assistance, update your question with the asp.net source code

Answer (score 0):

Please see if your server response has the same counter value for `draw` or `sEcho` property as sent by the client.

Example, request may contain `draw: 11` or `sEcho: 11` parameters, then, the server response must contain `draw: "11"` or `sEcho: "11"`.